# Security risk for making the sudo password timeout infinite?

Tags: 12.04, sudo

I recently changed my sudo password timeout (the amount of time that passes before sudo asks you for your password again). It defaults to 15 minutes; I raised that to an hour with `sudo visudo` and  changing `Defaults    env_reset,timestamp_timeout=60`. You can make sudo never ask for a password again, however, by setting it to -1.

While I have a feeling that every admin under the sun will tell me this is a bad idea, I'm wondering what the specific security risks are. If someone is logged in as me, don't they already have my password? What specific scenario will having a non-infinite password timeout protect me from?

My Ubuntu box runs a web server exposed to the public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sudo timeouts apply only to the current shell session. Try this:

- Open a terminal
- Run `sudo ls`. You will be asked for a password
- Run `sudo ls` again. You will not be asked for a password because the timeout hasn't yet expired
- Open another terminal window
- Run `sudo ls` in the new terminal. You will be asked for your password even though the timeout for the first session hasn't expired yet.

Your biggest risk of long sudo timeout is if you use sudo and then go for a coffee someone might reuse your sudo capabilities while you are away.

Comment: This is exactly the information I was looking for. So, it only applies to my current session, and that means in theory it's mostly safe to do.

Comment: Either that, or just run a root shell `sudo -i` When done or leaving your workstation / server, exit out of the shell.

Comment: By default it applies to your current terminal session.  You can however set timestamp_type to global, and all the login session then share this timestamp.  I don't know if that feature was present in sudo in 2014… I suspect it still used only tty_tickets, though the effect is, I think, the same,

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but I believe that the accepted answer lacks an important consideration. Depending on your usage, having a sudo timeout other than `0` can be dangerous:

Let's say you type a command with `sudo`. Then sometimes later, you use package managers like Pip for Python or NPM for Node to install new software or dependencies for your projects. Well, if your `sudo` timeout hasn't expired, then anything in these package will be able to execute a command as `sudo`.

It can also happen with code pasted from the internet, as demonstrated here:
https://martin-ueding.de/posts/the-dangers-of-sudo-timeout/